# Flask Request fails (400) when a *different* endpoint is changed

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I had this app working fine, and then I started reworking my redis handler class and I'm getting a 400 error in my React client from my `robot` endpoint when I make changes to my `state` endpoint.

I have a very simple API for the `robot/start/` and `robot/stop/` endpoints:

```py
def create_robot_api(api: Api, db: AsyncGetSetDatabase):
    robot_endpoint = api.namespace('robot')

    robot_model = api.model('Start/Stop', { 'counter': fields.Integer })

    def set_counter(action):
        counter = request.get_json()['counter']
        run(db.set_and_publish(f'{action}_request_counter', counter))
        return {'message': f'{action} request counter set to {counter}'}, 200
        
    @robot_endpoint.route('/start/')
    class StartRobot(Resource):
        @robot_endpoint.expect(robot_model, validate=True)
        def post(self):
            return set_counter('start')

    @robot_endpoint.route('/stop/')
    class StopRobot(Resource):
        @robot_endpoint.expect(robot_model, validate=True)
        def post(self):
            return set_counter('stop')
```

My `state` endpoint fetches relevant pieces of state from my db:

```py
def create_state_api(api: Api, db: AsyncGetSetDatabase):
    state_endpoint = api.namespace('state')

    @state_endpoint.route('/')
    class SystemState(Resource):
        def get(self):
            state = {}
            props = [ ... ]

            # this is old API and won't work.
            async def action(_db):
                for prop in props:
                    state[prop] = await _db.get(prop) or 0

            # run(db.execute(action))   # 1

            # return state              # 2 

            # THIS does the state correctly but causes post not to work!
            return run(db.get_keys(props)) #3
```

My React app makes a call to `get /state/` on startup, and has a button that calls `post /robot/start/` (as well as some buttons to `get /config/` and `post /config/` which both work fine)

When lines 1 and 2 are uncommented and I refresh the React app, the `state` endpoint itself causes an error in Flask -- a TypeError, which makes sense because the `db` actually has a new API which line 3 accounts for -- as well as a CORS error in chrome:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/state/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I comment lines 1 & 2, and uncomment line 3, the `state` endpoint returns as it should, works completely correctly. However, then when I click my UI's start button for `post robot/start/`m I get an error:

> POST http://localhost:5000/robot/start/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Also strange, is that calling the `post /start/` from my Swagger UI has no problems. It's only from the React app. FWIW, Flask output always shows `OPTIONS` and `POST` from React, in the good and bad cases. Swagger is always just `POST`. I've also tried removing `get /state/` from UI, then loading the UI, then calling `get /state/` from Swagger: start/stop is fine in the UI.

So it seems like there's something about making it through `get /state/` without an error, called from the UI, that causes this. In the React app only. This problem happens even if I replace the entire `get` function of the `state` endpoint with `return {}`. I've also tried having the `robot` methods just return 200.

And I swear it all worked before. There's been a lot of changes to my redis wrapper but they shouldn't have any affect on this!

Comment: i'm probably way to bad at this, but have you tried using a try and catch function around it and print out the exact error  message, which causes the 400 reponse?

Comment: I think the 400 means it doesn't even get to my flask code.